# Creating Parameterized SQL Queries in Excel 2010 with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I came across the following link:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=135

In it, they list relatively simple code to query the SQL Database from Excel VBA.

```
' Declare the QueryTable object
Dim qt As QueryTable

' Set up the SQL Statement
sqlstring = "select au_fname, au_lname from authors"

' Set up the connection string, reference an ODBC connection
' There are several ways to do this
' Leave the name and password blank for NT authentication
connstring = _
 "ODBC;DSN=pubs;UID=;PWD=;Database=pubs"

' Now implement the connection, run the query, and add
' the results to the spreadsheet starting at row A1
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), Sql:=sqlstring)
 .Refresh
End With
'Save and close the macro, and run it from the same menu you accessed in step 2.
```

This works fine. However, I want to be able to pull a value(s) back as a variable instead of dumping it to Excel.

Can someone assist me with that? I've tried looking for Excel VBA SQL Tutorials, but it seems that half the code I find doesn't work (perhaps because I don't understand it well enough).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ADO, for example:

```
''Reference: Microsft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim param1 As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

With cn
  .Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
  ''See also http://connectionsstrings.com
  .ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=test;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
  .Open
End With

Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@SiteID", adBigInt, adParamInput)
param1.Value = 1
cmd.Parameters.Append param1

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    ''Stored procedure
    .CommandText = "spSiteInformation_Retrieve"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    Set rs = .Execute
End With

For Each f In rs.Fields
  Debug.Print f.Name; " "; f
Next

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Further information: http://w3schools.com